# invalidPipeArgument date only on Ipad

Tags: angular

i'm trying this site in different platforms and i just realized that the DatePipe i'm using in angular does not work only in the Ipad but in mac and windows it does.
this is the way i'm using it in the html: `{{ item.start.date | date: dateFormat : 'UTC' }}`.
and this is the value if fateFormat : `dateFormat = 'dd/MM/y';`
the error that displays on Ipad is this:

```
IvalidPipeArgument: 'Unable do convert" 2023-09-28 10:00:00+00:00" into a date' for pipe 't'
```

Comment: In what IOS did you test it?

Comment: @Kostas Nitaf
 i tried on ios12.5.5

Comment: this might help you: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54768911/angular-6-date-pipe-not-showing-anything-on-iphone-safari-browser

Comment: @Kostas Nitaf thank you i'll try it, and make you know if it works after a while